# remove duplicates from the two array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have stuck to the following problem of removing the duplcation of array

```
$result=array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#489 (5) { ["id"]=> string(2) "64" ["block_from_id"]=> string(3) "117" ["block_to_id"]=> string(3) "329" ["block_status"]=> string(1) "0" ["username"]=> string(5) "pppoo" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#490 (5) { ["id"]=> string(2) "65" ["block_from_id"]=> string(3) "117" ["block_to_id"]=> string(3) "590" ["block_status"]=> string(1) "0" ["username"]=> string(3) "Pet" } } 

$customerlist= array(7) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#491 (5) { ["customer_name"]=> string(4) "User" ["profile_image"]=> string(47) "http://pet.huarisnaque.com/pet/upload/90113.png" ["jid"]=> string(18) "user128@canopus-pc" ["customer_id"]=> string(3) "128" ["phone"]=> string(10) "4784784784" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#494 (5) { ["customer_name"]=> string(6) "Khatru" ["profile_image"]=> string(46) "http://smartpetmanagement.com/upload/61694.png" ["jid"]=> string(20) "khatru321@canopus-pc" ["customer_id"]=> string(3) "321" ["phone"]=> string(10) "9686838386" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#495 (5) { ["customer_name"]=> string(5) "pppoo" ["profile_image"]=> string(46) "http://smartpetmanagement.com/upload/35210.png" ["jid"]=> string(17) "yyy329@canopus-pc" ["customer_id"]=> string(3) "329" ["phone"]=> string(10) "9525538835" } [3]=> object(stdClass)#496 (5) { ["customer_name"]=> string(7) "Xitxitx" ["profile_image"]=> NULL ["jid"]=> string(21) "xitxitx330@canopus-pc" ["customer_id"]=> string(3) "330" ["phone"]=> string(10) "6535383535" } [4]=> object(stdClass)#497 (5) { ["customer_name"]=> string(25) "The Following Document yf" ["profile_image"]=> string(46) "http://smartpetmanagement.com/upload/13712.png" ["jid"]=> string(39) "the following document yf589@canopus-pc" ["customer_id"]=> string(3) "589" ["phone"]=> string(10) "9535383535" } [5]=> object(stdClass)#498 (5) { ["customer_name"]=> string(3) "Pet" ["profile_image"]=> NULL ["jid"]=> string(17) "pet590@canopus-pc" ["customer_id"]=> string(3) "590" ["phone"]=> string(10) "6560530537" } [6]=> object(stdClass)#499 (5) { ["customer_name"]=> string(10) "Sanjay Pra" ["profile_image"]=> NULL ["jid"]=> string(24) "sanjay pra599@canopus-pc" ["customer_id"]=> string(3) "599" ["phone"]=> string(10) "2828282822" } }
```

there are two arrays,we need to remove duplicate records from the array containing two elements from result having elements from the customerlist.
here is my approach

```
for($i=0;$i<count($customerslist);$i++)
         {
             for($j=0;$j<count($result);$i++)
             {
                // if($result[$j]->block_to_id==$customerslist[$i]->customer_id)
                 {
                     unset($customerslist[$i]);
                 }
                     echo $result[$j]->block_to_id."<br/>";
             }
         }
```

Comment: Please provide the correct array

Comment: what do you means to say, the arrays are correct but the keys are different

Comment: any error ?  or don't get any result ?

Comment: @HarshitSethi you got an error of `Notice: Undefined offset: 2` if you unset the array inside the loop because the size of the array changes when you unset it. The index you produce does not match anymore because one of the index is remove and the size of the array is reduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unset the values after you find the indexes that has the duplicate. Because if you unset it inside the for loop of checking your duplicates it will produce this error because the size/count of the array changes and the index does not match anymore:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 2

So my solution is you can put the matching indexes on another array then unset them on another for loop shown bellow:

```
$result=array(
array('id' => 64, 
    "block_from_id" => 117,
    "block_to_id" => 329,
    "block_status" => 0,
    "username" => "pppoo"),
array("id"=> 65,
    "block_from_id"=> 117,
    "block_to_id"=> 590,
    "block_status"=> 0,
    "username"=> "Pet"
    )
);

$customerlist= array(
array("customer_name" => "User" ,"profile_image" => "http://pet.huarisnaque.com/pet/upload/90113.png" ,"jid" => "user128@canopus-pc" ,"customer_id" => "128" ,"phone" => "4784784784"),
array("customer_name" => "Khatru" ,"profile_image" => "http://smartpetmanagement.com/upload/61694.png" ,"jid" => "khatru321@canopus-pc" ,"customer_id" => "321" ,"phone" => "9686838386"),
array("customer_name" => "pppoo" ,"profile_image" => "http://smartpetmanagement.com/upload/35210.png" ,"jid" => "yyy329@canopus-pc" ,"customer_id" => "329" ,"phone" => "9525538835"),
array("customer_name" => "Xitxitx" ,"profile_image " => NULL ,"jid" => "xitxitx330@canopus-pc" ,"customer_id" => "330" ,"phone" => "6535383535"),
array("customer_name" => "The Following Document yf" ,"profile_image" => "http://smartpetmanagement.com/upload/13712.png" ,"jid" => "the following document yf589@canopus-pc" ,"customer_id" => "589" ,"phone" => "9535383535"),
array("customer_name" => "Pet" ,"profile_image " => NULL ,"jid" => "pet590@canopus-pc" ,"customer_id" => "590" ,"phone" => "6560530537"),
array("customer_name" => "Sanjay Pra" ,"profile_image " => NULL ,"jid" => "sanjay pra599@canopus-pc" ,"customer_id" => "599" ,"phone" => "2828282822")
);
echo "Before:". sizeof($customerlist) ."<br>";
print_r($customerlist);
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
$match = array();

for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($result) ; $i++) { 
    for ($ii=0; $ii < sizeof($customerlist) ; $ii++) { 
        if ($result[$i]['block_to_id'] == $customerlist[$ii]['customer_id']) {
            $match[] = $ii;
            echo " Match INDEX on result $i == customerlist $ii<br>";
        }
    }
}
for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($match) ; $i++) { 
    $ii = $match[$i];
    unset($customerlist[$ii]);
}
echo "<br>";

echo "After: ". sizeof($customerlist) ."<br>";
print_r($customerlist);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Before:7
Array ( [0] => Array ( [customer_name] => User [profile_image] => http://pet.huarisnaque.com/pet/upload/90113.png [jid] => user128@canopus-pc [customer_id] => 128 [phone] => 4784784784 ) [1] => Array ( [customer_name] => Khatru [profile_image] => http://smartpetmanagement.com/upload/61694.png [jid] => khatru321@canopus-pc [customer_id] => 321 [phone] => 9686838386 ) [2] => Array ( [customer_name] => pppoo [profile_image] => http://smartpetmanagement.com/upload/35210.png [jid] => yyy329@canopus-pc [customer_id] => 329 [phone] => 9525538835 ) [3] => Array ( [customer_name] => Xitxitx [profile_image ] => [jid] => xitxitx330@canopus-pc [customer_id] => 330 [phone] => 6535383535 ) [4] => Array ( [customer_name] => The Following Document yf [profile_image] => http://smartpetmanagement.com/upload/13712.png [jid] => the following document yf589@canopus-pc [customer_id] => 589 [phone] => 9535383535 ) [5] => Array ( [customer_name] => Pet [profile_image ] => [jid] => pet590@canopus-pc [customer_id] => 590 [phone] => 6560530537 ) [6] => Array ( [customer_name] => Sanjay Pra [profile_image ] => [jid] => sanjay pra599@canopus-pc [customer_id] => 599 [phone] => 2828282822 ) ) 

Match INDEX on result 0 == customerlist 2
Match INDEX on result 1 == customerlist 5

After: 5
Array ( [0] => Array ( [customer_name] => User [profile_image] => http://pet.huarisnaque.com/pet/upload/90113.png [jid] => user128@canopus-pc [customer_id] => 128 [phone] => 4784784784 ) [1] => Array ( [customer_name] => Khatru [profile_image] => http://smartpetmanagement.com/upload/61694.png [jid] => khatru321@canopus-pc [customer_id] => 321 [phone] => 9686838386 ) [3] => Array ( [customer_name] => Xitxitx [profile_image ] => [jid] => xitxitx330@canopus-pc [customer_id] => 330 [phone] => 6535383535 ) [4] => Array ( [customer_name] => The Following Document yf [profile_image] => http://smartpetmanagement.com/upload/13712.png [jid] => the following document yf589@canopus-pc [customer_id] => 589 [phone] => 9535383535 ) [6] => Array ( [customer_name] => Sanjay Pra [profile_image ] => [jid] => sanjay pra599@canopus-pc [customer_id] => 599 [phone] => 2828282822 ) )
```

Comment: thank the logic works, and also works on the objects